# How to get Angular's <router-outlet> to work with CSS Grid

Tags: css, angular, angular7, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout with Angular 7 and CSS Grid. The problem I have is that the `router-outlet` only takes up one column in the second row.

I have created a [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipbztw).

As you can see in `app.component.css` I want `router-outlet` (and any of its content) to take up `grid-column: 2 / 5`, as of now it takes up 2 / 3.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: have you looked into using bootstrap? the bootstrap grid would be ideal for this

Comment: No, it's the same result whether I go with css or scss. I don't want to use Bootstrap.

Comment: the bootstrap grid is literally designed for doing column stuff, its light and efficient

Comment: There is no need to add bootstrap for a simple css grid.

Comment: here, *Angular 7* and *CSS Grid* is used, don't suggest frameworks to be used by the OP... if you know how to solve the question as it is, tell OP that...

Comment: OP, on my end, the stackblitz doesn't have any issue, did you happen to resolve it ?

Comment: Why not enclosed your router-outlet between a <div class="main"> and add class to .main (not [main])?

Comment: I guess the OP's problem is that he thinks `router-outlet` has content, instead, all the router-driven templates are rendered **next to router-outlet**. This is by Angular design and this is what one should consider while using CSS flex and grid.

Comment: You can't apply CSS styles to child web components that have view encapsulation enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<router-outlet>` has no size and does not have any content in it, the actual router content is the next element to it. Remove the styles from `<router-outlet>` and only apply it to the next element to that and you should be fine.

Also, your `app.component` tries to apply styles to components that are not included in your component. You have to specify this explicitly by using `ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component definition. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmpnkl

Answer (score 14):

I think the problem is that you are trying to apply the style directly to `<router-outlet>`. Instead, create a "main div" element and put the router outlet inside of it.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I've updated [your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-osghap) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks! very simple and elegant solution. I was trying to deal with router-outlet added adding the content element next to it, which was screwing up my grids. Your solution solved my grid issues, thanks!

Comment: Any specific reason you used main as a custom attribute opposed to the `<main>` html-tag?

Comment: As @RobMonhemius I am also interested in why you used main as a custom attribute opposed to the <main> html-tag. Anyway good answer. This layout also can be done just with Flex.

Comment: It's been awhile since I looked at this question, but I believe that `main` attribute came from OP. My stackblitz was merely a fork and I intended to make a few changes as possible while solving the problem. You can see how it's being used in the CSS. Personally, I would have just used a simple class.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason not to globally define:

```
router-outlet
{
   display: none;
}
```

The actual Component element gets added after `router-outlet`, but there's never anything visible inside `router-outlet` itself.