# TailwindCSS not working in Angular (lazy loaded) Child component

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I have been struggling trying to make TailwindCSS work with Angular. I followed some tutorials and looked in the documentation of Tailwind. For some reason in certain places in the Angular 9 application it's working and in lazy loaded modules it's not (so it seems)!

So first thing I did was following and implementing these tutorials:

https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45

https://dev.to/beavearony/building-tailwind-css-in-an-angular-cli-project-e04

I know for sure I have these installed correctly because of the following:
My sidebar(app-sidebar) is having the correct css and styling! But the page I'm on loaded through the  is not.

I will provide you with my app-routing.module, and the default layout and the dashboard component. On this Dashboard the tailwindCSS is not loading. (Funny thing: if I add an H1 element with no class, no nothing I see this element on the dashboard page!) The other elements which contain some kind of tailwindCSS class don't. Also if I drag-and-drop through the content of my dashboard component to outside this dashboard component I see my elements, although without any styling. (I do this with Chrome DevTools)

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)   
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

**default-layout.component.html**

```
<div class="h-screen flex overflow-hidden bg-gray-100">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

    <div id="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<div class="flex flex-col w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="md:hidden pl-1 pt-1 sm:pl-3 sm:pt-3">
      <button class="-ml-0.5 -mt-0.5 h-12 w-12 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-200 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="Open sidebar">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <main class="flex-1 relative z-0 overflow-y-auto pt-2 pb-6 focus:outline-none md:py-6" tabindex="0">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
        <!-- Replace with your content -->
        <div class="py-4">
          <div class="border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200 rounded-lg h-96"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /End replace -->
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

The following I have tried but no succes:

ViewEncapsulation ([How to get Angular's <router-outlet> to work with CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868967/how-to-get-angulars-router-outlet-to-work-with-css-grid))

Added on each page a link to the CDN with tailwindCSS

Does it maby has any thing to do with the lazy loaded module?

Or maby that there is a double router-outlet?
Because this is how my **app.component.html** looks

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: How do you import tailwindCSS in your application?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I know for 100% sure the tailwindCSS is imported. I checked this with tailwind specific code. The problem had nothing to do with Tailwind not being installed correct. Because a child component in Angular is put in it's own element the tailwindcss connection got lost. What I  you can see my own answer

Comment: I just wanted to see how you import it. As you said, it might not be related however it might help us solve the problem

Comment: Added my answer ;) @BunyaminCoskuner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have figured it out. There were actually two things left I had to do.
First was to set the tailwindcss configuration **(tailwind.config.js)** and attach it to tailwindcss with the help of my **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    module : {
      rules: [
        {
          test   : /\.scss$/,
          loader : 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident  : 'postcss',
            syntax: 'postcss-scss',
            plugins: () => [
              require('postcss-import'),
              require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
              require('autoprefixer')
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Second thing I had to do was putting the overall class of the component to the host in my Angular Component.

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  host: {
    class: "flex flex-col w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden"
  }
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

So looking back at my question and looking at the **dashboard.component.html** file, the highest div is removed and the class of that div is placed in host! Like above.

I have followed the first link in my question!