# component is loading outside router-outlet

Tags: angular

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
   <app-aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 px-2"></app-aside>
   <router-outlet class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 px-2"></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

**outoput**

```
<app-aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 px-2"></app-aside>
<router-outlet class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 px-2"></router-outlet> 
<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
```

i am trying to load component inside router-outlet. but its not happening. New in angular so have less knowledge about deep level difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey try this,

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 px-2">
        <app-aside></app-aside>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 px-2">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Make sure that you have responsive content for the router-outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Angular use this html, It should look like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You need to remove the class and not use this as an html element, what you can do with it specified [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet).

More about this you can read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868967/how-to-get-angulars-router-outlet-to-work-with-css-grid).

Comment: only router-outlet i tried it bro, but i didn't worked