# Why is router-outlet a real DOM element?

Tags: angular

Today I saw that router-outlets don't get replaced by components, components get inserted after them as siblings. So, as the title says, why is router-outlet a real DOM element? Most other angular things end up as comments, eg

```
<ng-container>Inside container!</ng-container>
<div *ngIf="true">Inside conditional div!</div>
```

becomes

```
Inside container!
<!--ng-container-->
<div _ngcontent-xlm-c97="">
  Inside conditional div!
</div>
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
```

Surely the people at Google have thought about this, so what is the reason for this design choice?

In my specific case, I have two elements that need to be beside each other, of which the latter is inserted by the angular router. The resulting DOM is of the form

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
</div>
```

Apparently, the router-outlet has a non-zero size, and bootstraps grid-layout breaks. I found a solution proposed by the last answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868967/how-to-get-angulars-router-outlet-to-work-with-css-grid), putting

```
router-outlet {
   display: none
}
```

globally. This fixes my problem, but it seems so obvious I wonder if there's a reason why this is not the configuration out of the box? No one commented on that answer. If I build my app like this, is it going to cause problems in the future?